# Access a component of a RadScheduler control using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

I'm using RadScheduler control. I want to access the appointment click event using jQuery.

Like this:

```
$("#rs").click(function(e) {
    ShowDialog(true);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

`rs` is my scheduler. I want when click on the appointment not the whole control (scheduler). How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll can use Firebug or another debugger to inspect the control and determine which element you want to catch the click event of. And then adjust your jQuery to target that element instead of the outer element.